# PowerShell script to set default value on a metadata (termstore) column in a SP 2010 document library?

Tags: powershell, metadata

Is there a PowerShell script that will set the default value for a metadata (termstore) taxonomy column in a SharePoint 2010 document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirjam describes how to do this using code (C#) [here](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/01/07/setting-a-default-value-for-a-managed-metadata-field.aspx). Shouldn't be to hard to convert her code to a PS script.

Comment: Thanks Colin - Mirjam's link led me to Donald Hessing's post which provides the details.